# python: calculate time spent in status written in a dict

Tags: python, jira

I'm working on a script for gathering JIRA statisctics
for now I'm stuck on calculating of 'Time in status'

After some magic with JIRA API 
I have a dictionary:

```
{   
'2014-12-25T16:47:08': 'In Progress',
'2015-05-25T19:47:54': 'INFO Request',
'2015-06-05T11:04:00': 'In Progress',
'2016-04-15T19:22:01': 'Postponed',
'2017-02-07T12:12:58': 'In Progress',
'2017-02-07T12:13:22': 'Postponed',
'2017-08-12T19:02:59': 'In Progress',
'2018-11-13T18:00:38': 'Resolved',
'2018-11-13T18:03:03': 'Closed'},
```

well, atm I had written this thing:

```
def calc_in_status(dic):
formt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
res_dic={}
for key,value in dic.items():
    if value not in res_dic and value != 'Closed':
       res_dic.update({value: datetime.strptime(key, formt)})
return res_dic
```

for now it results into an initial dict i.e.

```
{   'In Progress': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 2, 16, 50, 37),
'PM Review': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 16, 16, 21, 52),
'Postponed': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 21, 13, 12, 46),
'Resolved': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 7, 16, 52, 13)}
```

I need some help to calculate how much time the ticket had spent in all of the above statuses. 
And I have no idea how to iterate through this, while finding then ticket changed it's status,calculating and writing timestamp differences to a resulting dict.

Comment: What problem do you face when iterating?

Comment: I simply don't know how to make my script tracking status changes and calculate the aggregate result :(

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of OrderedDict

Comment: tried, got
TypeError: 'odict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: Could you post your new code?

Comment: well, I just solved it by shittycode:
divided dict into two lists (of values and keys) and iterated using indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object1 = datetime.strptime('2014-12-05T16:47:08', '%Y-%m-%dT%X')
datetime_object2 = datetime.strptime('2014-12-25T16:47:08', '%Y-%m-%dT%X')
```

You can find the time difference between two datetimes simply by subtracting:

```
datetime_object2 - datetime_object1
```

To iterate through the dictionary:

`for key in my_dict.keys():
       ...`

Given your use-case, you shouldn't use a dictionary as it won't maintain any order of contained objects. Consider using an [OrderedDict](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html), which is much like a dict except that it also remembers the order of its elements.
Example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_data = OrderedDict([('In Progress', datetime_object1),
                       ('PM Review', datetime_object2)])
time_diff = my_data.items()[1][1] - my_data.items()[0][1] # Subtract the date of the second item from the date of the first item
```

Comment: I've updated the initial message, could you please take a look?